# Why is my array not getting modified?

Tags: c++, arrays, quicksort

Below is my code for quick sort and for whatever reason a[] is not getting modified. I compared this with the ones available on internet and it looks fine. Why is this happening ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void quicksort(int a[], int h, int l)
{
    cout<<"enters the function";
    for(int i=0;i<=h;++i)
        cout << "value" << i << "=" << a[i];

    int low = l;
    int high = h;
    int mid = a[(low+high)/2];
    do
    {
        while(mid > a[low])
        {
            low++;
        }

        while(mid < a[high])
        {
            high--;
        }

        if (low < high)
        {
            int t = a[low];
            a[low++] = a[high];
            a[high--] = t;
        }

    } while(low <= high);

    if(low < h)
    {
        quicksort(a,low,h);
    }

    if(high > l)
    {
        quicksort(a,l,high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "enter size";

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int d[15];
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        cin >> d[i];

    quicksort(d,0,n-1);

    cout << "the sorted array=";
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        cout << d[i] << ',';

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same array I entered without any changes.

Comment: If you want people help you can you at least format your code properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you call quicksort with high = 0 and low = n-1.  Your arguments are reversed.

BTW: The code formatting is different from what most C++ programmers expect, but thank you for providing code that actually compiles and runs.

Comment: Oh :D. Thank you so very much. I spent so much time on this thing and now I feel so stupid.

Comment: @user2715898 welcome in the club :)